# Help Creating Geometric Shapes as a Class

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.drawing

how do I create a geometric shape as a class? Visual basic has a Rectangle class pre-defined object that I would like to use, but I need to use a rectangle class that can use decimals for the 4 points to set its location.  I do not want to draw a shape on the form for graphical reasons but I want to use the shape for an algorithm, how can I create a class for a rectangle using decimals?  Thanks and I am a beginner using visual basic so I would appreciate help in as much detail as possible. Thanks again in advance

Comment: @Oded: It has to be VB.NET. It's the only one that has a `System.Drawing` namespace and a pre-defined `Rectangle` class.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I figures it probably was .NET, but wanted the OP to confirm (and learn the difference). The OP doesn't mention namespaces either.

Comment: @Oded: Fair. My tendencies have become to clarify these types of questions as quickly as possible, before an flood of inaccurate answers pours in. Good point about getting the OP to clarify and learn the difference though.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, sorry I didn't clarify but I did mean vb.net.  Thanks Cody this was very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use decimal values for the four points of the rectangle, you need to use the [**`RectangleF` structure**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef.aspx), instead of the regular `Rectangle` structure. It accepts values of type [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx), and is already built-in to the .NET Framework.

The `F` at the end of the name stands for "floating-point", which refers to the decimal point. Computers store numbers with decimal points a bit differently than they do integers. Rather than being fixed at any specific position, the position of the decimal is allowed to "float". A pretty complicated concept to explain in an answer to such a simple question, but you can get a detailed explanation [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) if you're confused.

(By the way, the `Rectangle` and `RectangleF` objects are actually *structures*, rather than classes.
It's a distinction that probably seems somewhat minor or even irrelevant when you're first learning the language, but it becomes important later. All you need to know right now is that when you're defining your *own* types, you should always use a class rather than a structure.)

Answer (score 0):

In the newer .NET (3.0+) there is

```
System.Windows.Rect(WindowsBase.dll)
```

This has Double precision. It behaves the same as Rectangle and RectangleF.